Swift property wrapper value in struct not updating view
I just learned about Swift's property wrappers from Nick Sarno's YT video and they seem pretty cool. I'm investigating and I created a property wrapper to uppercase a string:
@propertyWrapper
struct Uppercased: DynamicProperty {
    @State private var value: String
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get {
            value
        } nonmutating set {
            value = newValue.uppercased()
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.value = wrappedValue.uppercased()
    }
}

Then I can include it in a view like:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Uppercased private var str: String = "pork on the fork"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(str)
            Button("New string") {
                str = "chicken on the knife"
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


When I press the button the text updated.
Problem
However, when I put the @Uppercased value inside a nested strut which is then out into the main view with @State, the UI does not update, even when the structure conforms to DynamicProperty too.


Uppercased already has a @State. By wrapping Model in another @State, the view would be observing the "outer" @State, not the "inner" one that stores the str. The "outer" @State can't see any changes when you change the "inner" @State. It doesn't work for the same reason as why
@State @State private var str = "Foo"

doesn't work.
Removing the outer @State and just writing
private var model = Model()

in the View would work. But it will not observe changes to the non-DynamicPropertys in Model.
For such general-purpose property wrappers as Uppercased, I'd suggest not making it DynamicProperty.
@propertyWrapper
struct Uppercased {
    private var value: String
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get {
            value
        } set {
            value = newValue.uppercased()
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.value = wrappedValue.uppercased()
    }
}

If you really want a DynamicProperty, you can create a DynamicProperty version of the above like this:
@propertyWrapper
struct UppercasedState: DynamicProperty {
    @State private var value: Uppercased
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get {
            value.wrappedValue
        } nonmutating set {
            value.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.value = Uppercased(wrappedValue: wrappedValue)
    }
}

Use @UppercasedState in SwiftUI structs like View/ViewModifier, and use @Uppercased everywhere else.

Thanks @Sweeper for your answer, appreciated and I get how using 2 @States doesn't update the UI. But the solution is still a little confusing.
So if I add var t = "A" to the Model and some text/button to show/change the t variable similar to str I cannot update the t because self (the view) is immutable.
Also, using the UppercasedState would not that do the same thing as Uppercased? It looks like it would have no benefit since I would still want to use @UppercasedState in a model and the model in a @State variable in a view.
Thanks a lot!

@DanielCrompton I think you misunderstood what I meant. You should use @Uppercased in your models and @UppercasedState in your views. Whether that "has no benefit" or not is up to you.

@DanielCrompton In case you missed it - there are two versions of Uppercased. Uppercased alone cannot act like a DynamicProperty sometimes and act like a normal property wrapper in other times.

Great that makes sense now @Sweeper thank you for your help! :)
